# Windows partition requirements?

Tags: windows, partitioning

I have an Ubuntu-only system and need to install Windows on it. Because all my Linux partitions are in an [LVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29), the Windows partition may only reside after all the Linux partitions (in other words: at the 400GB mark).

I don't want to do all the work of resizing the LVM just for the Windows Installer to tell me he doesn't fancy my partition setup. There are are all kind of requirements floating around the net, such as:

- has to be the first partition on the first device (this is wrong, AFAIK)
- has to be a primary partition
- has to be on the first 10|20|100|132|whatever Gigabytes
- has to be on the first X cylinders
- and so on and so forth...

So, what are the *actual* requirements for a Windows partition? It would be Windows 7, if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no limitations whatsoever. Windows 7 can be installed on any NTFS partition. You will be ok. However...

It will wipe out your boot sector with its own code and so, you'll need your Ubuntu disk to replace it back with GRUB.

FYI, [Adding Windows 7 to Linux Multiboot](http://blog.lokonopa.com/grub-up-windows-7/).

Comment: You're right, Windows 7 didn't complain being installed at the end of a 500GB disk. Thanks for your help!